# Strange character in the Highstock source code

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I was looking at the most recent code for highcharts, when I saw this segment:

```
wrap(opacityHook, 'get', function (proceed, elem, computed) {
    return elem.attr ? (elem.opacity ||Â 0) : proceed.call(this, elem, computed);
});
```

Why is there an Â character in the source code? That couldn't be right, could it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like that's a quick way of throwing an exception when, in this case, said element property (`elem.opacity`) is [falsey](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/truthy-falsey/).

Running the following statement throws a "runtime" error:

```
alert(elem.opacity ||Â 0);
```

Writing that is shorter than writing:

```
alert(elem.opacity ? elem.opacity : throw 'some error message');
```

*Note: the `throw` statement will not work as expected (writing to the console "some error message") -- as the ternary expression should return a value.*

Thus, `(elem.opacity ||Â 0)` suffices and keeps the code concise/terse and defensive, but not very semantic ...

---

**In Short**

The following:

```
... (elem.opacity ||Â 0) ...
```

Translates to:

Throw an error if `elem.opacity` is `undefined`.